# Needed spark-assembly-1.5.2.-hadoop2.7.jar for Spark -Oozie workflow on HDP 2.3.2

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, oozie-coordinator, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to schedule spark 1.5.2 job on oozie 4.2.0 (HDP 2.3.x). Spark 1.5.2 has been installed externally i am not using default spark version provided by hortonworks. I am referring below post to set this up.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7014/oozie-sparkaction-throwing-javalangnosuchmethoderr.html

I am struggling to find below jars.

-spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar

-spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.0-3485-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.jar

If you can help me with some pointers to find/download above jars it will be a great help to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in spark lib path

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib
```

You can find

```
[ram@IP lib]$ ls
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar  datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar               spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar  spark-hdp-assembly.jar
datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar    spark-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-yarn-shuffle.jar  spark-examples-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar
[ram@IP lib]$
```

Then copy the needed libs to your workflows lib

```
eg: hadoop fs -put /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/* YOUR_WORKFLOW/lib
```

Comment: Ram as mentioned, we are not using Spark which comes with HDP. The reason is Spark which comes with HDP is version 1.4.x we need spark 1.5.2 hence we installed spark 1.5.2 externally and using spark 1.5.2 on Yarn and HDFS. But struggling to schedule spark job on ooze.To make spark 1.5.2work with oozie i need park-assembly-1.5.2.-hadoop2.7.jar. If you are using Spark 1.5.2 with oozie can you please share the assembly jar.

Comment: `wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`
`tar -xvf spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`
`cd spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib`
`[ram@IP lib]$ ls
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar  datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar  datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar  spark-1.5.2-yarn-shuffle.jar  spark-assembly-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar  spark-examples-1.5.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar
[ram@IP lib]$`

Then copy the needed libs to your workflows lib
`eg: hadoop fs -put /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/* YOUR_WORKFLOW/lib`

Then change in job.properties
`oozie.use.system.libpath=false`

Comment: Ram i have assembly jar for 1.5.2 Hadoop 2.6 i need Spark 1.5.2 with hadoop 2.7